# Is the computer-related term "character" understood by the general population?

Tags: vocabulary, technical

The following kind message is common in programming:

> Your password must be at least six
>   characters long and include at least
>   one letter and one number

Would an average person understand what that message means?

Is it reasonable to assume they'd understand the distinction between a character and a letter?

Is there a better, jargon-free, way to phrase this message that does not sound torturous?

Comment: I think it's pretty clear for everyone. If someone does not understand the difference between character and letter he will just use letters anyway, so that would be fine anyway.

Comment: I always wonder the same thing about the word "string".

Comment: @tenour: I don't think string is clear for laymen. No way my mother would get that. Characters, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is pretty common to understand *character* as as *printing press character* when for instance you read about characters in a broad sense of all the types used in printing.

My edition of the OED has this definition as number I.3a, that is pretty much at the top of the list:

> I.3.a esp. A graphic symbol standing for a sound, syllable, or
>   notion, used in writing or in
>   printing; one of the simple elements
>   of a written language; e.g. a letter
>   of the alphabet.

And indeed everyone would talk about *Chinese characters* which aren't really letters.

Answer (score 1):

As you mention yourself, this is common. This is the message that we see across websites when creating a password. I think the average person understands this without problems. If you are unsure, make the word "characters" into a link-type word that you can hover over to get an explanation of what is implied.